# How to link an add-ons to a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have read some documentation about the notion of "installed or enabled editor add-ons" but I didn't understand very well. I have developped an add-ons that work with a specific google sheet template. The rule is that I will make some copy of the sheet model and distribut them to collaborator or they will do themselves the copy of the model and work on it.

I would like to know if it's possible to link the add-ons to the doc and in that way my collaborator don't need to search the add-on on G-suite store because ideally the copy of my google sheet template will offer the possibility to install the linked addon directly in the menu of the google sheet.

Finally from what i understood here,https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle

> Authorization model
> Two properties of editor add-ons make them especially easy to share and use:
>
> - Once you get an editor add-on from the store, you see it in the Add-ons menu for every
>   you open or create. Collaborators on those documents won't see the add-on except in documents
>   where you actually use it.
> - Once you use an editor add-on in a document, your collaborators also see it in the Add-ons menu,
>   but just for that document (unless they have also installed that add-on).

I would like to have the second exemple and not the first.

Thank you for your answers guys

Comment: So, your question is whether an add-on can be attached to a template? If that's the case yes, this can be done. You just may have to [install the add-on in order to use it](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148833?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Have you tried doing it? Are you having problems with it?

Comment: Yes I have juste try it before and you right, but I confused myself.. I thought that there was 2 way to publish add-on but in reality its just 2 status, now the issue I have is that when I make a copy of a sheet with add-on enabled, the copy has not the add-on enabled

Comment: What are you doing to `enable` the add-on?

Comment: The add-on is enabled when I install the add-on while I am on the google sheet